# Identifying highly variable genes in scRNA-seq: Seurat vs M3Drop

Tags: seurat, single-cell

Following a [single-cell RNA-seq workshop](https://rnabioco.github.io/cellar/previous/2019/docs/3_norm_viz_clustering.html), I created a Seurat object (`my_data`), normalized the data, and then tried to identify highly variable genes using two different R packages: `Seurat` and `M3Drop`.

```
variable_genes_Seurat <- my_data %>%
  FindVariableFeatures(selection.method = 'vst', nfeatures = 2000) %>%
  VariableFeatures()

variable_genes_M3Drop <- my_data %>%
  GetAssayData('counts') %>% # unnormalized
  NBumiConvertData() %>%
  NBumiFitModel() %>%
  NBumiFeatureSelectionCombinedDrop(ntop = 2000) %>%
  rownames()
```

I compared the results and found out that the gene lists were pretty different and shared only 588 of 2000 genes:

```
shared_variable_genes <- intersect(variable_genes_Seurat, variable_genes_M3Drop)
length(shared_variable_genes)
> 588
```

My questions are:

1. Why are the results so different?
2. Which feature list - `shared_variable_genes`, `variable_genes_Seurat` or `variable_genes_M3Drop` - should I use for dimensionality reduction and clustering?

Thank you!